# Connecting Facebook on an application

Tags: javascript, facebook

Everytime I log out my account on Facebook itself, the connected account (same account) in the app also logs out. Is this expected?

I was hoping to come up with something like Hootsuite's functionalities, starting with Facebook first.

Here is my code.

```js
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
var app_id='{!#SETTINGS.facebook_api_key#value}';

function statusChangeCallback(response) {
 console.log('statusChangeCallback');
 console.log(response);
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
  console.log('The user is connected.');
  var fb_access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  console.log(fb_access_token);
  rbf_setFieldValue("facebook_access_token", fb_access_token);
 } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
  console.log('The user is not authorized.');
 } else {
  console.log('The user is not logged in.');
  FB.login(function(response) {
   console.log('Logging in.');
   var fb_access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
   console.log(fb_access_token);
   rbf_setFieldValue("facebook_access_token", fb_access_token);
  }, {scope: 'public_profile, manage_pages, publish_actions, user_groups'});
 }
}

function checkLoginState() {
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
 });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
 FB.init({
  appId      : app_id,
  cookie     : true,
  xfbml      : true,
  version    : 'v2.1'
 });

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  statusChangeCallback(response);
 });
};

// Load the SDK asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

My mistake was I used FB.ui for posting to Facebook, and it requires a Facebook account to post.

The solution was to use FB.api and pass the user/page access token so that you can post without user login.

```js
function postToSocialTimeline() {
  try {
    var obj = {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      link: link,
      picture: picture,
      caption: caption,
      message: "Test",
      access_token: accessCode
    };

    function resp(response) {
        console.log('Cancelled');
      } //FB.ui(obj, resp);

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'POST', obj, function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log(!response ? 'error occurred' : response.error);
        console.log('Error');
        alert('Unable to post to Facebook!');
        return;
      } else {
        alert('Requisition has been successfully posted!');
      }
    });
  } catch (e) {}
}
```